# How to prevent Rstudio Server from overriding GIT_ASKPASS on startup

Tags: r, git, rstudio, rstudio-server

With Rstudio-server 2023.12.0 Build 369 on ubuntu 20.04, I am trying to set the GIT_ASKPASS environment variable for the Rstudio session.

I have tried setting it in the Renviron.site file as well as in ~/.Renviron. I also tried setting it to the value I need in ~/.Rprofile and in ~/.bashrc.

In all cases I see that what I set it to gets overridden somewhere in the RStudio startup, such that in the R console in RStudio if I run `Sys.getenv('GIT_ASKPASS')` I get `rpostback-askpass` , which is NOT the value that I set it to or that I need.

I see that my code in ~/.Rprofile runs on startup, and I even print there a `message` with the value that I need (after setting it there with `Sys.setenv(GIT_ASKPASS='my_special_value')`).
Nevertheless, in the R console `GIT_ASKPASS` still evaluates to `rpostback-askpass`, and in the `terminal` window in RStudio it seems that `GIT_ASKPASS` somehow is not set at all.

Clearly something in the RStudio Server startup sequence is overriding the value I set for `GIT_ASKPASS` after Renviron.site, ~/.Renviron, ~/.Rprofile etc. all run.

How can I prevent RStudio Server from overriding the value that I set for `GIT_ASKPASS` ?